# Best way to download .db from url and use it. Android Studio

Tags: android, sqldb

What is the best way to download .db from url and use it in my app?

Thanks for help. I was looking a lot in google but no one method helped me.

I'm using
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
and
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to download .db from url and use it in my app?

The same way you would download anything from a URL: use an HTTP client API, such as the built-in `HttpUrlConnection` or third-party libraries like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Download the database to a location that you get from calling `getDatabasePath()` on `Context`, to store it in the default directory that `SQLiteOpenHelper` will use.

After the database is downloaded, you can open it using `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: Can you show me an example how to save data from web using okhttp? I don't understand it and i can't find it on Web.